# Google Sign In Integration is Not Working in my App after Upload in play store, why?

Tags: android, gmail

I am using google+ for getting gender in google sign in integration

Debug Apk and Signed(release)Apk is working fine.
but after upload play store and download App from play store gmail is not working.
I tried[enter image description here][1]
1.I using relese SHA1 key configured with firebase and download json_service file and past into project-->App
2.i tried To generate SignedApk i am taking V1(Jar Signature) And V2(Full Apk)Signatures.
3.i tried to generate SignedApk i am taking only V1 (Jar Signature) only

Still i dint get solution,
if click gmail just blinking one time only
Could give solution any one please?

Comment: This might be an issue with the keystore file. Do check it. Can't predict the exact issue unless some related information is provided

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sign In Integration is Not Working in my App after Upload in play store. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174682/google-sign-in-integration-is-not-working-in-my-app-after-upload-in-play-store)