# Google Sign In Integration is Not Working in my App after Upload in play store. why?

Tags: gmail

I am using google+ for getting gender in google sign in integration.

Debug Apk and Signed(release) Apk is working fine. 
But after upload play store and download App from play store gmail is not working.

I tried:

1. using release SHA1 key configured with firebase and download json_service file and past into project-->App
2. to generate SignedApk I am taking V1(Jar Signature) And V2(Full Apk)Signatures.
3. to generate SignedApk I am taking V1 (Jar Signature) only

Still I didn't get solution, if click gmail just blinking one time only Could anyone provide a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of Upload SignedApk In Play store,
It will Creates a new SHA1 Key in App Signing Certificate.
Take that SHA1, Add in your Google Console and Firebase Account
It will work.

New SHA1 will be found at Released Management->App Signing on your play console.